# How do I print a single number to the console in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I tried to print a number to the console: The mathfunction should return

> the sum of the squares of the two larger numbers

```
(ns myapp.core)





(defn mathfunction [a, b, c]
    (let [x (max a b c)
         lst (remove #{x} '(a b c))
         y (max((first lst) (first (rest lst))))]
            (+ (Math/sqrt x) (Math/sqrt y))))



(defn -main [& args]
    (println (mathfunction(1 5 3))))
```

And just to make sure that not my mathfunction is the problem:

```
(defn -main [& args]
    (println 5.4))
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to
>   clojure.lang.IFn

So what did i do wrong?

Comment: Just a little thing: You can use one let for all 3 let operations. And i tried exetuting your mathfunction and it does not work, so maybe the error is in there.

Comment: This does not seem like resonable clojure code to me. #(max(a,b,c)) dosen't make much sense, most likely it should be (max a b c).

Comment: Also the remove function takes 2 arguments. What is it you wanted to try? maybe we can help there.

Comment: this is just an exercice for me trying to learn clojure. My problem is that i don't understand why print can't print numbers or how to convert them

Comment: i cleaned up my code and described what the math function does

Comment: You have a problem in (max((first lst) (first (rest lst))))

Comment: and what kind of problem?

Comment: `(defn -main [& args] (println 5.4))` produces no errors for me. Then executing `(-main)` and `(main 47)` also produces no errors for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem in :

```
(mathfunction(1, 5, 3))
```

What you need is:

```
(mathfunction '(1, 5, 3))
```

Or:

```
(mathfunction (list 1 2 3))
```

Because in (mathfunction (1, 5, 3)) , 1 is a number not a function and that is why you are getting:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

Also, this is wrong for the same reason above:

```
(max ((first lst) (first (rest lst))))
```

And what you need is:

```
(max (first lst) (first (rest lst)))
```

Remember that in Lisp, the first element in list is a special thing. It is called: ***Function Position***.

Comment: As `mathfunction` takes 3 arguments, not one list, what is needed is `(mathfunction 1 5 3)`

Comment: @TerjeD. True. The original question was edited a couple of times. But you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

For that what you want to do, that way may be more idiomatic for clojure:

```
(defn mathfunction [& args]
  (let [a (apply max args)
        rem (remove #(= % a) args)
        b (apply max rem)]
    (+ (Math/sqrt a) (Math/sqrt b))))
```

Also you need to call it like (mathfunction 1 2 3) and not like (mathfunction (1 2 3)).

The latte ris interpreted as a funciton call with 1 as the function and 2,3 as the parameters.